# Show that the equation $f(x) = 0$ has no solution.

Tags: functions, derivatives, polynomials

The polynomial $f$ is given $f(x) = x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+12$, show that the equation $f(x) = 0$ has no solution.

I´ll have a test and they gave me some practice questions, the only one I don´t know how to answer is this one, I searched online, but I wasn´t able to understand how to do it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You have the derivative tag.  Did you try taking the derivative?  What did you get?  And what have you tried?

Comment: This equation has $4$ solutions over $\Bbb C$. What domain are we talking?

Comment: I haven´t tried anything because I have no clue on how to prove that f(x) will never be 0

Comment: Perhaps the question should really be: The polynomial $f$ is given $f(x) = x^4-4x^3-2x^2+12x+12$, show that the equation $f(x) = 0$ has no **real** solution.

Comment: Show that the minimum value is $>0$. Note that $f$ goes to $+\infty$ when $|x| \to \infty$. Hence a $\min$ exists. Differentiate and look at the values of $f$ at the roots of $f'$. More subtle reasoning will tell you that you only need to evaluate $f$ at one of the roots of $f'$ but this just saves two evaluations of $f$.

Comment: You can prove that $f(x)$ is never zero if you can show that it has a global minimum which is a positive number. How can you find the minimum of a polynomial?

Comment: Hmm, swap one and two in my comment above. Someday I will write a mathematical sentence without bugs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you differentiate $f(x)$, you should end up with $f'(x) = 4x^3 - 12x^2-4x+12$ which you can factor as $f'(x) = 4\cdot[x^2(x-3) -(x-3)]=4(x^2-1)(x-3)$. Assess whether each of the roots of $f'(x)$ corresponds to a minimum or a maximum of $f$, or neither. Deduce that $f$ has two global minima which are positive at $x = 3$ and $x=-1$. Since $f(x)\to+\infty$ as $|x|\to+\infty$, conclude that $f$ has no real roots.

---

**Edit:** The factorization of $f'(x)$:
\begin{align*}
4x^3-12x^2-4x+12 &= (4x-12)x^2-4(x-3) \\
&= 4(x-3)x^2-4(x-3) \\
&= 4\cdot[x^2(x-3)-(x-3)].
\end{align*}

Comment: You missed $x=\pm1$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yep, noted. Nice catch.

Comment: With which rule/method you factorized this polynomial?

Comment: @RodrigoCv Check my updated answer.

Comment: @RodrigoCv Notice the similar coefficients: $4, -12, -4, 12$. You can alternately write this as $(4x^3-12x^2)-(4x-12)$ from which you can see the next step.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to do for yourself is trying to image this graph, and the line $y = 0$, what does it mean for these two functions to have no solution when they are put in an equation together? If you can answer this, then it should be rather straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way to do this kind of question is to show $(\forall x)\,\,f(x)>0$ or  $(\forall x)\,\,f(x)<0$.

Showing this usually involves finding the solutions to $f'(x)=0$ for the turning points. $f''(x)$ will tell you the nature of these turning points, and you may be able to conclude from there.

In addition, showing $(\forall x)\,\,f''(x)>0$ or $(\forall x)\,\,f''(x)<0$ shows $f$ is convex or concave respectively which is sometimes helpful.

---

In your example,

$$f(x)=x^4−4x^3−2x^2+12x+12$$

$$f'(x)=4x^3−12x^2−4x+12=4(x^3-3x^2-x+3)$$

$$f''(x)=12x^2−24x−4=4(3x^2-6x-1)$$

Note $f'(1)=0$, so using the factor theorem (and polynomial long division),

$$f'(x)=4(x-1)(x^2-2x-3)$$

$$=4(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)$$

Now $f''(-1)=8>0, f''(1)=-4<0, f''(3)=8>0$ so the points are a minimum, maximum, minimum respectively. The curve has no more turning points, and so $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}f(x)=\infty$

Finally, $f(-1)=3, f(3)=3$, and hence $(\forall x\in \mathbb{R})\,\,f(x)\ge3\gt0$.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial can be written as

$$f(x)=\left(x^2-2 x-3\right)^2+3$$
therefore it is strictly greater than zero for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$